# How to create browse file button in Kendo UI Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a custom button on **Kendo UI editor** that has a browse file feature.

[image]

I have this line in my toolbar:

```
{
 name: "Add",
 template: '<a class="k-button" id="popupbutton"   onclick=" events.toolbar_click(\'theFile\')">Command</a><input type="file" id="theFile" hidden/> ',
}
```

That does not seem to work. And the code below is what basically I am trying to do but in **Kendo editor**.

```js
function performClick(elemId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  if(elem && document.createEvent) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

```html
 
<a href="#" onclick="performClick('theFile');">Open file dialog</a>
<input type="file" id="theFile" hidden/>
```

Looking for help to make this feature on 1-button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The first one is with a custom template, just like you have setup. However, I am not sure what is "events.toolbar_click". Here's how you can get it to work:

**Method 1**

```
<script>
          function performClick(elemId) {
              var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
              if(elem && document.createEvent) {
                var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
                elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
              }
          }

          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
                  items: [
                    { name: "Add", type: "button",
                      text: "File", template: '<a class="k-button" id="popupbutton" onclick="performClick(\'theFile\')">File Command 1</a><input type="file" id="theFile" hidden/> '} ]
              });
          });
</script>
```

The other way to do this is by using the toolbar's buttons' event handler.

**Method 2**

```
<input type="file" id="theFile" hidden/>
<script>
          function fileClickEventHandler(){
            performClick('theFile')
          }

          function performClick(elemId) {
              var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
              if(elem && document.createEvent) {
                var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
                elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
              }
          }

          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
                  items: [
                      { type: "button", text: "File Command 2", click: fileClickEventHandler },
                  ]
              });
          });
</script>
```

You can see both examples working here: https://dojo.telerik.com/eLUbiXAF

Comment: Great example! I think I made a mistake with my question. It is not actually a toolbar , it is an Kendo UI editor. The hidden parameter does not work for me on the editor. and if I do display:none, var elem = document.getElementById(elemId) returns undefined , because it can not see the input form

Comment: Can't you put the input element outside of the Kendo Editor?

Comment: I just actually did that and hide it with JQuery. Does the job for now. Thanks